# get image from cross domain through http call in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, cross-domain, jsonp

I am trying to get  an image from cross domain  and I tried this

```
var img = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=bc7c2f3904bf";
     $http.jsonp(img).success(function() {
                  console.log("success");

       }).error(function() {
                  console.log("failure");
       });
```

I just want to check whether the image is exist, if exist I want to show that iage, else I want to show a div instead of img.

and I am getting this error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Anything I missed here

Any help could be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: That's probably not the best way to do this. Can you give more details of what are you trying to do? You can probably just create an img element and then set the SRC to the Image you want.

Comment: I just want to check whether the image is exist, if exist I want to show that image, else I want to show a div instead of img.

Comment: I've posted a possible  solution

Answer (score 0):

Understanding what is your objective, I think you should do this way:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function() {
    //put Image on dom
}

img.onerror = function() {
    //put div on dom
}
```

Hope it helps :)